# std::bad_alloc when sending lidar data over a ROS network

Tags: c++, string, ros, point-cloud-library, lidar

I am trying to send lidar data using the ROS network. For this, I perform an octree compression with the PointCloudLibrary(PCL) available in ROS. The compression outputs the result in a stringstream. Since this cannot be send over the ROS network, I convert it to a string and publish it as an std_msgs::String.

At the decompression side, I convert the std_msgs::String to a string and then place it in a stringstream. This stringstream is then given to the decompression function of the PCL library. The decompression function requires an input stream as input. The output of the function is then converted to a sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 and published to the ROS network again.

When I run the program with the compression algorithm(code 1), everything works fine. I can see the string getting published correctly. When I run the program with the decompression algorithm(code 2), I get a std::bad_alloc error. It seems to happen when the string is placed into the stringstream.

Any help would be appreciated.

Code 1, program for compression:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
// PCL specific includes
#include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h>
#include <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h>
#include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/visualization/cloud_viewer.h>

#include <pcl/compression/octree_pointcloud_compression.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>

ros::Publisher pub;

pcl::io::OctreePointCloudCompression<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>* PointCloudEncoder;

void 
cloud_cb (const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& input)
{
  // Create a container for the data.
  std::string output;
  std_msgs::String outputString;


  //convert to pointxyzrgba type
  pcl::PCLPointCloud2 pcl_pc2;
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::Ptr temp_cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>);//convert to pointer to satisfy function requirement
  pcl_conversions::toPCL(*input, pcl_pc2);
  pcl::fromPCLPointCloud2(pcl_pc2, *temp_cloud); 



  // stringstream to store compressed point cloud
  std::stringstream compressedData;
  // output pointcloud
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::Ptr cloudOut (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA> ());

  // compress point cloud
  PointCloudEncoder->encodePointCloud (temp_cloud, compressedData);

  output = compressedData.str();
  outputString.data = output;

  // Publish the data.
  pub.publish (outputString);
}

int
main (int argc, char** argv)
{
  // Initialize ROS
  ros::init (argc, argv, "my_pcl_tutorial");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;


  //\\
  //setup compression algorithm


  bool showStatistics = false;

  pcl::io::compression_Profiles_e compressionProfile = pcl::io::LOW_RES_ONLINE_COMPRESSION_WITHOUT_COLOR;

  // instantiate point cloud compression for encoding and decoding
  PointCloudEncoder = new pcl::io::OctreePointCloudCompression<pcl::PointXYZRGBA> (compressionProfile, showStatistics);
  //\\



  // Create a ROS subscriber for the input point cloud
  ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe ("velodyne_points", 1, cloud_cb);

  // Create a ROS publisher for the output point cloud
  pub = nh.advertise<std_msgs::String> ("velodyne_points/compressed", 1);

  // Spin
  ros::spin ();
}
```

Code 2, program for decompression:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
// PCL specific includes
#include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h>
#include <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h>
#include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>

#include <pcl/compression/octree_pointcloud_compression.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>

ros::Publisher pub;

pcl::io::OctreePointCloudCompression<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>* PointCloudDecoder;


void 
cloud_cb (const std_msgs::String& input)
{
  // Create a container for the data.
  sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 output;
  // stringstream to store compressed point cloud
  std::stringstream compressedData;

  std::string s;
  s = input.data;

  compressedData << s;

  // output pointcloud
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::Ptr cloudOut (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA> ());

  // decompress point cloud
  PointCloudDecoder->decodePointCloud (compressedData, cloudOut);


  //convert to pointcloud2
  pcl::toROSMsg(*cloudOut, output);


  // Publish the data.
  pub.publish (output);
}

int
main (int argc, char** argv)
{
  // Initialize ROS
  ros::init (argc, argv, "decompressLidar");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;


  //\\
  //setup compression algorithm

  PointCloudDecoder = new pcl::io::OctreePointCloudCompression<pcl::PointXYZRGBA> ();
  //\\

  // Create a ROS subscriber for the input point cloud
  ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe ("velodyne_points/compressed", 1, cloud_cb);

  // Create a ROS publisher for the output point cloud
  pub = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> ("decompress", 1);

  // Spin
  ros::spin ();
}
```

Comment: `compressedData << s;` -- Not knowing the type of data `s` will store, if `s` can contain embedded NULL characters, then this is not how you would write to the stream.  You would use `compressedData.write(s, s.size());`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you for your response. This was indeed is the problem. I had to convert the string to const char first, but the string is now placed within the stringstream. I now get: "assertion: octree_oversized_x -minValue failed". Do you know anything about this by any chance?

Comment: Well, it's an `assert()`, so you should be able to use your debugger to see which code generated it.  At least tt's better than a seg fault.  Yes, the correct way is `compressedData.write(s.data(), s.size());`